# Representable morphisms of Artin stacks.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a representable morphisms $f:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{Y}$ of Artin stacks, do the fibers of $f$ have always nonnegative dimension? If not, can you give me some examples of what can happen?

Comment: It is not true. The identity map is a representable morphism whose fibers have dimension zero.

Comment: sorry, I meant nonnegative dimension

Comment: Yes, the fibers are algebraic spaces.

Comment: What is the dimension of the empty algebraic space?

Comment: Good point, Torsten. The fibers have nonnegative dimension everywhere.